# Como lidar com vários condicionais (if e else if seguidos) em Java e como compactá-los?

Tags: java, if, condição

Atualmente tenho um pequeno grupo de classes que implementam um joguinho de snake com dois jogadores.

Estou implementando os movimentos conforme o aperto das teclas, atualmente o código está assim:

```
    // #----- Classe anônima para lidar com os movimentos -----#

    private class Key implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                p1.getSnake().setDirection(new Right()); //se a tecla foi seta a direita p1 move
            } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                p2.getSnake().setDirection(new Right()); //se a tecla foi "d" o p2 move
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                p1.getSnake().setDirection(new Left());
            } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                p2.getSnake().setDirection(new Left());
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                p1.getSnake().setDirection(new Up());
            } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                p2.getSnake().setDirection(new Up());
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                p1.getSnake().setDirection(new Down());
            } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                p2.getSnake().setDirection(new Down());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    }
```

O método `keyPressed()` possui 4 `if` seguidos de `else if`, o código fica difícil de ler e o maven reclama que não é o jeito certo de programar, e me dá *checkstyle violation*.

Eu não tenho muito experiência em programação ainda, e não sei como re-escrever essa parte do código de maneira mais eficiente.

Como eu poderia melhorar a leitura e compreensão do método `KeyPressed()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem 4 ações diferentes, então pelo menos 4 `if`s devem ser usados. Cada ação acontece com duas condições diferentes, então não tem porque ter dois `if`s , basta concatenar as duas condições criando uma condição maior e completa. Para concatenar expressões condicionais e criar outra usa-se `&&` (um E) ou `||` (um OU). Ainda pode usar mais operandos mas esses são os principais. No caso você quer um OU outro, então é o que será usado. Algo assim:

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || key == KeyEvent.VK_D) p1.getSnake().setDirection(new Right());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/Conditional.java).

Faça o mesmo com os demais. Você pode usar o `else if` para melhorar o desempenho. Porque se ele entrar no primeiro não precisa entrar nos demais, então pode fazer um bloco só, algo assim:

```
else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || key == KeyEvent.VK_A) p1.getSnake().setDirection(new Left());
```